# Order List Dividers Based on Custom OrderBy Function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

Please see the CodePen below for clarification. I have a situation where I need to order the list dividers based on a "ParentId" field that is in each child of the parent. I have an array of ParentId's which specified the order that the parent items should appear in the list. How might I go about this? If you notice, I am losing the original order of my list dividers when using ng-repeat-start.

[**See CodePen Here**](http://codepen.io/jpmckearin/pen/Fymea?editors=101)

Answer (score 0):

You need orderBy:

```
<a class="item"
       ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'ParentId'">
      {{item.Description}}
    </a>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ltxfv

I messed with your parent ID's on purpose, so you can see what's happening.